# Reuse SQL Server cursor with different parameter value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I wonder whether cursor for query with `@variable` parameter can be re-used (`CLOSE` + `OPEN`) when value of the `@variable` changes. To me it looks that it always needs `CLOSE` + `DEALLOCATE` + `DECLARE` + `OPEN` to take new value of the `@variable` into effect. Perhaps no big deal, but **I wanted to know whether `DEALLOCATE` + `DECLARE` can be left out between uses.**

Here you have complete simple example to try it out:

```sql
DECLARE @ta TABLE (a int);
INSERT INTO @ta (a) VALUES (1),(2),(4),(8),(16),(32),(64);
---------
DECLARE @current_a int;
DECLARE @threshold int = 12;
DECLARE crs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT a FROM @ta WHERE a < @threshold;

--- first cursor use
OPEN crs1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM crs1 INTO @current_a;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @threshold, @current_a
            FETCH NEXT FROM crs1 INTO @current_a;
        END;    

CLOSE crs1;
DEALLOCATE crs1; -- can this be left out?

SET @threshold = 3;
DECLARE crs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT a FROM @ta WHERE a < @threshold;  -- can this be left out?

--- second cursor use
OPEN crs1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM crs1 INTO @current_a;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @threshold, @current_a
            FETCH NEXT FROM crs1 INTO @current_a;
        END;    

CLOSE crs1;
DEALLOCATE crs1;
```

This was linearized example, but the question applies also to *nested* cursors when outer cursor changes the query parameter of inner cursor.

Comment: Do you want something like `cursor variable`? Check **[demo](http://rextester.com/CIB55337)**

Comment: @lad2025 – yeah, I did not know cursor variables can do the job here. Please add this as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use [`cursor variable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx):

> ```
> DECLARE 
> { 
>     { @local_variable [AS] data_type  | [ = value ] }
>   | { @cursor_variable_name CURSOR }
> ```
>
> **@cursor_variable_name**
>
> Is the name of a cursor variable. Cursor variable names must begin with an at (@) sign and conform to the rules for identifiers.
>
> **CURSOR**
>
> Specifies that the variable is a local cursor variable.
>
> A cursor variable:
>
> - Can be the target of either a cursor type or another cursor variable. For more information, see SET @local_variable.
> - Can be referenced as the target of an output cursor parameter in an EXECUTE statement if the cursor variable does not have a cursor
>     currently assigned to it.
> - **Should be regarded as a pointer to the cursor.**

```
DECLARE crs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT a FROM @ta WHERE a < @threshold;
-- could be changed to
DECLARE @crs1 CURSOR;
SET @crs1 = CURSOR FOR SELECT a FROM @ta WHERE a < @threshold;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/CIB55337)**</kbd>